# byte order over custom buffer

Tags: c++, c, networking

I want to send a payload that has this structure:

```
uint8_t  num_of_products;
//1 product
   uint8_t  action;
   time_t unix_time;//uint64_t
   uint32_t name_len;//up to 256
   char* name;
   uint8_t num_of_ips;
   //1 ip out if num_of_ips
      uint8_t ip_ver; //0 error , 1 ipv4 , 2 ipv6
      char* IP;// ipv4 : 4 , ipv6 : 16
```

before sending the packet I aggregate products using `memcpy` into jumbo size `mbuf`

from tests I did `name_len` must go through hton in order to not look "inverted" in wireshark.

my question is ,what logic can I apply in order to get the byte order right for a custom structure with inner variables with unknown size

i.e what should go through hton what should be left as is

Comment: Just pick little or big endian and stick with it. Neither is wrong. Still, big endian order is usually chosen for serialization for some reasons.

Comment: Study endianess. The target CPU, the destination CPU and the network protocol all have endianess.

Comment: @AndreiAndrey The choise of endianess is not left to the programmer... (except maybe if exclusively programming microcontrollers with software selectable endianess.) As for why big endian is often used as protocol endianess, it goes back to the days when CRC checks were done in hardware with shift registers and XOR logic gates, which in turn required the FCS to be big endian. There's many protocols that use little endian as well though.

Comment: You write a function called `serialize`, it has knowledge of the structure, does the conversion and writes it to the buffer

Comment: If this is a well-known protocol, then you need to check the protocol specification for the endianess (i.e. if you set Wireshark to decode your data using predefined parsers). You will notice that IP and TCP headers use big endian, but if this is a custom protocol, there is no particular need in using big endian for the payload. If you are just designing the protocol, the easiest way to debug it would be to use strictly ASCII characters. If you want to save bytes, use protobuf or something similar. However, what you **shouldn't** do is just cast `int`s to a byte buffer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are aiming to have your message in network byte order (big endian), only your integer fields that take up more than one byte will need the htonl treamnet.  In your case, that would be `time_t unix_time` and `uint32_t name_len`.  Your strings and single-byte fields (such as `num_of_products`) won't need any specific conversion.

As some of the commenters in your question suggested - it's really up to you if you want to use a strict network byte order. Serializing your message to have a strict byte ordering is useful if you intend your code to run across different platforms.

Writing efficient byte packing code is annoyingly hard. You wind up writing a lot of code to just to save a few bytes of network bandwidth.

User `jxh` mentioned JSON as a possible encoding for your message. Not sure why he deleted his answer because it was on point.  But in any case, a standard messaging format of either JSON or XML (or any ascii text schema) is 100x easier to observe in wireshark and when debugging.